# Send password in welcome email in Django

Tags: django

I have a script that creates multiple users based on an excel file, and a signal that sends out a welcome email to the user. I'd like that welcome email to also include the password in plain text. I know it's not good practice and I should send the user a link to set their password, but time is unfortunately not on my side right now.

Is there a way to have the plain text password in the `post_save` signal?

Comment: You shouldn't have access to the user's password in plain text.

Comment: How are you generating the passwords that you expect to email out?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid via `User.objects.make_random_password()`

Comment: What about making a column in db that has plain password? Extend the user model and add plain-password field.

Comment: @user2707389 Weird, I won't sign-up...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stopped to think for a minute and came up with probably the best solution. I'm letting the script generate the users without any password, but with `user.active = False`, and inside the signal, I'm generating the password, setting `user.active = True` and sending the email with the password. This way, if for some reason the signal fails to be called, there won't be any security issues, the user will just not be able to log in.

Will switch to a better approach (sending the user a one-time reset password link) when I have the time.

Comment: the problem with this approach, inactive users cannot log in, "the default AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS reject inactive users."
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users

Comment: @diek true, however in my use-case, all users were set to active when generating the password and sending the email, so there were no inactive users left.

Comment: yes @Eduard , you are right of course, set to active at the same time as setting the password. I had a long day, I really like this approach. I am going to use it, thanks

Answer (score 6):

Saving plain text passwords or using post_save signal here, won't be that wise. While creating users use the following approach:

```
new_password = User.objects.make_random_password()
user = User.objects.create_user(username=data.name, email=data.email, password=new_password)
user.send_welcome_mail(new_password) // custom instance method to send a mail and the send password as parameter
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: You should note this isn't very safe either. It's better to generate a one-time-use link for the user to set the password on first login

Comment: Surely, but as mentioned above that is not an option here for the developer. :)